# async.each and http get

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous

I want to programmatically fetch meta tags from multiple urls and use for furthur processing.
I'm using this below code snippet, this one always prints only the first urls meta tag and the async callbacks res is undefined. Am I missing anything here with async?

```
var http = require('http'),
    cheerio = require('cheerio'),
    async = require('async'),
    urls = [
        "http://theatlantic.com",
        "http://nytimes.com"
    ];

    function test() {
    var $, data = '';

    getMetaData = function(uri, callback) {
        http.get(uri, function(resp) {
            console.log('Fetching Url:' + uri);

            resp.on('data', function (chunk){
                data += chunk;
            });

            resp.on('end', function () {
                $ = cheerio.load(data);
                console.log('Meta Tag:' + $('meta[property="og:description"]').attr('content') + '\n'); //use for furthur processing
                callback(null, $('meta[name="description"]').attr('content'));
            });
        });
    }

    async.each(urls, getMetaData, function(err, res) {
       console.log(res);
    });
};

test();
```

Comment: move 'var data' into getMetaData or else all your threads will write into the same variable...

Comment: It worked. But 'res' in callback is null instead of the meta description.

Comment: according to the documentation, that is correct: `The iterator is passed a callback(err) which must be called once it has completed. If no error has occurred, the callback should be run without arguments or with an explicit null argument.`. Also: you use `og:description` for console log and `description` for the callback... might that be it?